# findOrFail returning the correct and also a wrong record

Tags: laravel

I have a model called *Location* and am trying to get a specific entity: */api/location/2*

When I do that, I get the result for the record with ID of 2, but also an extra record:

```
{
id: 2,
name: "Considine Group",
address: "Rau Union",
uri: "http://localhost:6890/api/location/2"
},
{
id: 467,
name: "Lubowitz, Parker and Kuhn",
address: "Bernice Ports",
uri: "http://localhost:6890/api/location/467"
}
```

My *show* function in the controller is pretty simple:

```
    public function show(ShowLocationRequest $request, Location $Location)
    {
        $Loc = Location::with('company:id,name')->findOrFail($Location); 
        return response()->json(["data"=>$Loc],200);
    }
```

Even if i remove the *company* relation it does the same thing. FirstOrFail will throw an error: 
*Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters*. 

Looking in telescope, I see that the select statement is there as I would expect it to be:
**select * from `locations` where `id` = '2' and `locations`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1**

Here is where I get confused, just above that query in telescope there is one more (and final) query:

```
select
  *
from
  `locations`
where
  `locations`.`id` in (
    2,
    'Considine Group',
    'Rau Union',
    '13552 Fritsch Underpass',
    'Janellefort',
    'MO',
    '16407-4623',
    '',
    '467-980-9647 x03308',
    '',
    '',
    'nova.weimann@bartell.net',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    'active',
    0,
    '1573583520',
    '1573583520',
    'http://localhost:6890/api/location/2'
  )
  and `locations`.`deleted_at` is null
```

When I run that query manually in MySql workbench, i get both results just like in the response.

Can anyone help me understand where the issue is? I am able to reproduce this on other models. It is consistent among the same entity (location id 2 will always do it) but location id 3 will not. 

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing the whole `Location` model to `findOrFail`.

When you type hint the id, it does the query to find the `Location` model for you, and saves it to the variable. This is causing the `findOrFail` to look for every key in the collection you passed it. The second row its finding is due to the `id` existing in the phone number of location 2 probably truncated by the `-` after.

Instead of type hinting `$location` in the method, just do

```php
public function show(ShowLocationRequest $request, $Location)
```

This will cause your query to only search for the id in your route, instead of every key in the location model.

Option two is to leave the type hinting and load the relationships afterwards

```php
public function show(ShowLocationRequest $request, Location $location)
{
    $location->load('company,name');
}
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, but do you really think removing the type hinting is the right solution here? if the only thing OP is trying to do is pre-load that relation I'd really wonder if the performance benefit is worth it there.

Comment: You're probably right that its not worth it just for that. I only did it that way because the query wasn't just a find. I'll add the other option to my answer.

Comment: Thank you both for your help.